# C-u M-x - recompile error: "Wrong type argument: consp, nil"

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp, emacs24

If I do `C-u M-x recompile` inside a buffer that's not the `*compilation*` buffer, (i.e. the source file for instance), I get this error - "Wrong type argument: consp, nil" after it prompts for the compilation command.  Why is this?  I want to run recompile interactively as comint works, sometimes outside the compilation buffer.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `emacs -Q`, just to be sure (yes, I know you said you commented out all of your init file, but just to be sure -- and it's a lot easier to do than comment-out everything).

Next, set `debug-on-error` to t -- You can do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to do that, if you prefer.

Next, provoke the error and look at the debugger `*Backtrace*`. It will show you not only which function raised the error because it expected a cons and got `nil` instead, but also what function called it, passing the bad argument.  And so on down the stack.

If necessary, you can click `mouse-2` on functions on the stack (at the left, to see their source code. Or put the cursor on them and use `C-h f` to see their doc -- in particular, what arguments they expect and what their return values should be.

In this way it's pretty easy to find the code that is the culprit. (Most likely, in spite of what you said, it is some non-vanilla Emacs Lisp code you loaded somehow.)

Also, state your emacs version : `M-x emacs-version`.  If you are using a development snapshot then the problem could come from vanilla code (i.e., `emacs -Q`); otherwise, that's not so likely.

Also, you say you get the error after it prompts you.  Immediately after it prompts, before you type anything? After you type a command name and hit `RET`?  Try to be more specific.

---

**Update after your comment:**

Load library `compile.el` (not `.elc`). Then do `M-x debug-on-entry recompile`, then step through the debugger using `d` when function `recompile` is entered. What you are interested in is when `compilation-start` is called (applied to its args).

It seems that the value of `compilation-arguments` that is passed to it is no good.  The command name you enter at the prompt becomes the first of the list of `compilation-arguments`.  The others are taken from when you last invoked `compile`: `recompile` just reuses the same arguments (except the command name): `(mode name-function highlight-regexp)mode name-function highlight-regexp)`.

However, be aware that `compilation-arguments` is buffer-local.  So if you changed to a different buffer then its value is likely not what you need.  You need the value from your last `compile`, so you should do the `recompile` in the same buffer where you did `compile`.

(FWIW, I don't use `(re)compile` myself, as I don't develop software anymore.  I just took a look at the source code.)

Comment: I did emacs -Q and did `C-u M-x compile` and `C-u M-x recompile` in the scratch buffer (don't even need to do/have anything fancy to generate this problem).  Here's the output `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument consp nil)
  recompile((4))
  call-interactively(recompile record nil)
  command-execute(recompile record)
  execute-extended-command((4) "recompile")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)`.  What I would really like is for the compilation buffer to stop switching from comint mode to read-only non-interactive mode after I do recompile if that more clear

Comment: Hey also thanks a lot for explaining all those commands.  I really had no idea how to debug emacs lisp and do a backtrace.  This is really useful!  There is a long list of things I do not know about emacs, so when I learn something useful like this I really appreciate it.  Emacs version is 24.3.1 of 2014-01-03.  Also it's after I enter the command name and hit `RET` that this is happening.

Comment: There are two functions listed on the stack that are click-able (mouse-2).  `Recompile` and `execute-extended-command`.  Both say cannot find library `/(path-to-file/compile.el` and `/(path-to-file)/simple.el`, respectively. No joke.

Comment: Hm. Try `M-x find-library compile.el`.  Or do `C-h f recompile` and then click the file name `compile.el`.  Those will both take you to the source file.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of errors usually depicts a problem with your configuration. Try to investigate *messages* buffer output. There can be some clues there.

And of course, it is normal to call a recompile command from a buffer with your code. It is a convention to bind it to C-c C-c.

Comment: Just commented out my entire .emacs file and tried all steps manually as follows: `C-u M-x compile`, this opened interactive compilation buffer.  Then switched back to source code buffer, ran `C-u M-x recompile`.  Mini-buffer prompted me to enter the compile command (for some reason) hit RET, then same error.  It may be normal to run non-interactive recompile, but what if I need to run it interactively? I think its a bug to be honest, I'm running 24.3.1.  Here's message buffer output - (No files need saving)
call-interactively: Wrong type argument: consp, nil

Comment: It looks like that you're not doing anything wrong. Did the problem remain without C-u? And have you tried just to restart emacs?

Comment: I get no error with plain M-x recompile, but there is an input prompt terminal provided from the tool I am using.  If I don't run in interactive mode the compile buffer is read-only and I can't enter commands into the tools terminal.  I have tried restarting emacs btw with same results.  The actual problem I am having is that if I do M-x recompile out of the *compilation* buffer, the compilation buffer changes from interactive to non-interactive read-only.. which I'm thinking is a bug?

Comment: looks like a bug, certainly.

Comment: Just it add - it's like its kicking the *compilation* buffer out of comint mode, which I really don't think is supposed to happen.  Edit: Just saw your post!  Thank you for your help I do appreciate it!